# How to Apply Gateway Intents WITHOUT any Library in Discord API?

Tags: discord

I'm making the Dashboard using NextJS. I need to get guild member list so I made the API. but I have to apply Gateway Intents. I read docs but I still don't know how.

What I don't know:

- Where to apply Gateway Intents

Comment: What library are you using, is it discord.py or discord.js?

Comment: are you intending to use a bot? Or just the discord API?

Comment: only discord API

Comment: That's not how discord API works, you'll need to have a bot that is joined to that guild to get the member list and enable the intent at the discord developers portal

Comment: I made a mistake to say. I have a bot and I want to get the list of guild member that bot joined using discord API.

Comment: _"I will NOT use ANY LIBRARY"_, Geez, you tag two discord libraries and when someone asks which one you use, you just shout at them like it's their fault your question wasn't clear enough...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you make any API calls to discord, you'll have to make sure that you have the `GUILD_MEMBER` intent enabled under your bot's settings in the [Discord Developers Portal](https://discord.com/developers)

[image]

Once that's done, You can make a GET request [list-guild-members](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#list-guild-members) while making the get request, you'll need to send [Authorization](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#authentication) header with the request

here is an example in plain JavaScript

```js
let guild_id = '000000000000'
let bot_token = 'yourbottoken'

fetch(`discord.com/api/v10/guilds/${guild_id}/members`, {
method: 'get',
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": `Bot ${bot_token}`
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data));
```